# Is it possible to use natural units (particle physics units) with boost?

Tags: particle-physics, units, unit-conversion

I would like to use boost to handle my units in my c++ code, and I was wondering if it was possible to use natural units? That is, can I add a mass and a momentum and set it equal to an energy without having to multiply by the necessary c's everywhere?

Comment: From reading the Boost.Units documentation, it seems like units and dimensions are user-defined, so I don't see why not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using specific software, and not physics.

Comment: Note that a question about whether natural units are appropriate for computations would be on-topic (and has a non-trivial answer), while a technical questions about the unit-handling logic in the Boost library belong elsewhere.  If you want the former, editing your question will enqueue it for re-opening.

Comment: For me this would be better on SO

Comment: I think the version of the question that @rob suggest would be on-topic here, but might receive more attention on [scicomp.se].

Answer (score 0):

Any function that doesn't do any conversion can be used with any system of units. However, many functions take an object that implicitly defines the units. For example, the 'quantity' template is a value in a certain unit. I suppose you could call functions that don't do any conversion with a 'quantity' that is technically a wrong unit, yet it would still work, but that's very poor design.

Boost also can do dimensional analysis. So you can't, for example, pass a temperature as a distance. (But that's also horrendous design, anyway, of course).

See the 'quantity' template and this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units/Quantities.html#boost_units.Quantities.Heterogeneous_Operators